# Rails - manipulating data in popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup, bootstrap-modal

I'm new in Rails, I have a Meal model which has many Products. Meals are assign to User (maybe this is important for a concept). In meals/new.html.erb I want to create new Meal as follow:

1. Click the button "Display Products"
2. On the same page (meals/new.html.erb) open modal (pop-up) with all products assigned to current user ( I have help method for current-user). It should be displayad like a list or grid with checboxes for example.
3. Then user can check few products and click "Confirm".
4. After that in meals/new.html should be appeared list of chosen products with additional input to fill their quantity.

So I have two problem here.

1. How should I display modal? Is needed any Ajax (I'm not so familiar with this technology)
2. How can I pass products between view and modal?

Could you help me a little to achieve these goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first problem, displaying the modal is fairly straight forward. Essentially you will create a div with the proper bootstrap classes to be hidden when the page is loaded, and then create a button that makes it visible. I would recommend either reading over [the W3Schools entry](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) on modals, or from [the appropriate part of the bootstrap javascript documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples).

Regarding your second question, this depends on exactly what you mean. The modal is part of the view, so if you're only trying to put information that is currently on the modal back onto the "page" behind it, you can do so fairly simply with javascript (copying content out of one element into another, or updating states of inputs). If, on the other hand, you're trying to use the modal to retrieve information from the server (for instance if you wanted to show a list of possible options, and then display detailed information about the selected items from the database) that would require Ajax.

If you have any snippets of code that aren't functioning as you expect, feel free to add your View to the question. In cases like this, usually the best way for us to provide help is for you to take an early crack at this, post the relevant code, and then seek answers for the things that behave unexpectedly.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for a response. It directs me to a right way, I hope.